# 'Get-ECRLoginCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am trying to download a Docker image from AWS and following [the instructions at AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html#:%7E:text=(Get%2DECRLoginCommand).Password%20%7C%20docker%20login%20%2D%2Dusername%20AWS%20%2D%2Dpassword%2Dstdin%20aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com) I'm running:

```
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Get-ECRLoginCommand : The term 'Get-ECRLoginCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

How can I fix this error? I assume I need to install the module.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some searching, I realised I had omitted installing ECR when installing AWSTools. I had used these 2 commands:

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer -Force
Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.EC2,AWS.Tools.S3 -CleanUp
```

So I installed it with:

```
Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.ECR
```

After that it worked.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, running this command on the AWS CLI instead of the AWS tool for Windows PowerShell worked.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region [your region] | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin [your aws_account_id].dkr.ecr.[your region].amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue.
And there were serveral things that need to be done for the command to work.

The Permission `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` is required for the IAM-User.

The modules need to be installed

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Common 
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.ECR
```

After that it is required to set the credentials,
and tell the Credential-Manager that those are to be used as default.

```
Set-AWSCredential `
             -AccessKey <KeyName> `
             -SecretKey <Key> `
             -StoreAs <Profile>

Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName <ProfileName> -Region eu-central-1
```

(Documentation is scattered, which makes following the guide tricky for me, but here are the sources [Credential specification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html), [Creating Access Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey) )

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue use this format command instead the one suggested on the ECR `View Push Command`

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com
```

replacing the red fields by your correct data.

Also check that your aws.config file is in the correct format.

You can find more info here:

[Working format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html)

[Correct config file formatting](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cli-unable-parse-config-file-credentials)